# How to modify Get-ADGroupMember to run for multiple groups from csv, to replace nested groups with members of the said groups

Tags: windows, powershell, for-loop, scripting, active-directory

Hi Im trying to write a script to replace nested groups with members of said group. I found one from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1816091-ad-powershell-replace-nested-groups-with-members-of-said-group
and modified as follows. Where **#Parent_1** is an AD distribution group.

```
$TargetGroup= '#Parent_1'
ForEach ($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup) {
    if ($Member.objectclass -eq 'group') {
        
        ForEach ($SubMember in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Member -Recursive ) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup -Members $SubMember.SamAccountName 
             
        }
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup -Members $Member -Confirm:$false
  
    }
}
```

**It works perfectly fine for a single group that is "#Parent_1" when used as $TargetGroup.**

But I wish to run it more than one for **$TargetGroup** using a **CSV** as follows.

Instead of using **$TargetGroup= '#Parent_1',** I wish to have **$TargetGroup =Import-Csv -Path .\xx.csv**

With the following CSV.

[image]

But it won't run, just by replacing that. It just gives errors.
[image]

Did several modifications, yet casting different different errors time to time, could not make it. Not sure we need another for each loop.

Can anyone please help ? Any help would be appreciated.

---

**PS answer for my question | Final working code**

```
foreach($TargetGroup in Import-Csv -Path .\xx.csv)
{

    ForEach ($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname)
    {
        if ($Member.objectclass -eq 'group')
        {
            ForEach ($SubMember in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Member -Recursive)
            {
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname -Members $SubMember.SamAccountName 
            }
            Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname -Members $Member -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop one `$TargetGroup at a time`

```
foreach($TargetGroup in Import-Csv -Path .\xx.csv)
{
    ForEach ($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup)
    {
        if ($Member.objectclass -eq 'group')
        {
            ForEach ($SubMember in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Member -Recursive)
            {
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup -Members $SubMember.SamAccountName 
            }
            Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup -Members $Member -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. had to add $.TargetGroup.samaccountname, yet it works with an additional loop

Comment: Very good. I think you could also use identity or distinguished name, but both are untested.

Answer (score 0):

@Doug thanks.. **$TargetGroup** should be $**TargetGroup.samaccountname** for internal loops in this way.. and its works! perfect.

```
foreach($TargetGroup in Import-Csv -Path .\xx.csv)
{

    ForEach ($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname)
    {
        if ($Member.objectclass -eq 'group')
        {
            ForEach ($SubMember in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Member -Recursive)
            {
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname -Members $SubMember.SamAccountName 
            }
            Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $TargetGroup.samaccountname -Members $Member -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}
```